# UK - Where to get blank EIS claim form

Tags: united-kingdom, self-assessment

I want to submit EIS claim form, but the form I got from the company is accidentally damaged, so I want to find the blank form, print it and submit. But for some weird reason I just cannot find the blank EIS claim form anywhere. Does anyone know where I can get my hands on one?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, what form exactly are you trying to submit? I'm only aware of claiming EIS relief as part of a Self Assessment claim (which you can do online). Are you talking about EIS3 / EIS5 which the company would have sent to you? You can't get a blank one of those and fill it in yourself as it would have been issued by the company.

Comment: Oh I think I get it now. You're trying to submit the EIS3 claim sheet which is attached to the EIS3 form you got from the company?

Comment: @Vicky I want to submit it via post to claim relief for the previous tax year. Afaik you cannot do that online

Comment: I think your best bet will be to email HMRC to ask for a clean copy of the form (or email the company that issued it and ask for a re-issue).